# How to integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} e^{x(-a+i\xi)} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I solve this integral for an arbitrary a, $\xi$ and integer n>0?
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}  e^{x(-a+i\xi)} dx$$
I tried to integrate it by parts, but got stuck

Comment: Are you sure about its convergence?

Comment: Try calculating $\int_0^\infty e^{tx} e^{x(-a+i\xi)} \,dx$ and expand as a power series in $t$.

Comment: WA gives the following answer $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\Gamma
   (n+1) (a-i \xi )^{-n-1}}{n!},\Re(n)>-1\land
   \Re(a)+\Im(\xi )>0\right]$$

Comment: If you are permitted to use contour integration, and $a\gt0$, then it is pretty easy to get $(a-i\xi)^{-n-1}$

Comment: @Manthanein: It should converge as far as i know.

Comment: Certainly you need $a > 0$. I think this is the only condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Denote $$I_n := \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-b x} dx .$$ Then, following your suggestion to apply integration by parts, we take (for $n > 0$) $u = x^n$, $dv = e^{b x} dx$, formally giving
$$I_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left[ \left.x^n \cdot -b^{-1} e^{-b x}\right\vert_0^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} -b^{-1} e^{- b x} \cdot n x^{n - 1} \,dx \right] .$$

The first term in brackets converges iff $\operatorname{Re} b > 0$, in which case it converges to $0$.

> So, for such $b$, we have $$I_n = b^{-1} \cdot \frac{1}{(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty} x^{n - 1} e^{- b x} dx = b^{-1} I_{n - 1}, $$ and induction gives $I_n = b^{-n} I_0$, but $$I_0 = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-b x} = b^{-1} ,$$ so $$I_n = b^{-n - 1}.$$ We set $b = a - i \xi$, so the integral is $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-b x} dx = (a - i \xi)^{- n - 1}}} ,$$ provided that $\operatorname{Re} a > 0$ (assuming that the parameters $a, \xi$ are real).

Comment: When you use this substitution, $x\mapsto\frac{x}{a-i\xi}$, the path of integration changes from $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}[0,R)$ to $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}[0,(a-i\xi)R)$. We can use [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) to show that the integral over the paths are the same, but the equality must be justified.

Answer (score 2):

If $\Re z>0$, $\int_0^\infty \exp -zx dx=[\frac{1-\exp -zx}{z}]^\infty_0=\frac{1}{z}$, because $$\lim_{x\to\infty}|\exp -zx|=\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp -x\Re z =0\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp -zx=0.$$Applying $\frac{1}{n!}(-\partial_z)^n$, $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\exp -zx dx=\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}$. Now we just take $z=a-i\xi$, which is fine if $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody stated, for the convergence you have to have $a>0$. Supposing that's true , we can solve the integral by using the gamma function $$\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^\infty x^n e^{x(-a+i\xi)}\,\mathrm dx$$ doing the following substitution 
$$
\begin{align*}
t = -x(-a+i\xi) \implies &x = \frac{t}{a-i\xi}\\[5pt]
&\mathrm dx = \frac{\mathrm dt}{a-i\xi}
\end{align*}
$$

which gets us $$\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{t}{a-i\xi}\right)^n e^{-t}\,\frac{\mathrm dt}{a-i\xi}$$ we take everything that doesn't depend on $t$ outside the integral $$\frac{1}{n!(a-i\xi)^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{n!(a-i\xi)^{n+1}}$$ from the properties of the Gamma funcion and being $n$ an integer we know that $$\Gamma(n+1) = n!$$ so finally $$\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{n!(a-i\xi)^{n+1}} = \frac{n!}{n!(a-i\xi)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{(a-i\xi)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: When you use this substitution, $x\mapsto\frac{x}{a-i\xi}$, the path of integration changes from $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}[0,R)$ to $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}[0,(a-i\xi)R)$. We can use [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) to show that the integral over the paths are the same, but the equality must be justified.